# Interface с реализацией

Tags: java, интерфейс

Я во всех учебниках видел, читал, тестировал `interface` с методами без реализации. Но вот копаюсь в дереве и тут есть методы с реализацией `default`. Это как понять? То есть можно реализовать интерфейс с реализацией??? Спасибо.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Можно определить интерфейс с реализацией. Эта возможность появилась в *Java 8*, в более ранних версиях она была недоступна. Вот пример реализации такого интерфейса:

```
interface Test {
    default int test(int i) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Если в классе, реализующем этот интерфейс, метод не переопределяется, то будет использована дефолтная реализация из интерфейса.

Фактически, начиная с *Java 8*, интерфейс приобрёл некоторые черты обычного класса и стало возможным реализовать некий аналог множественного наследования.

Comment: Есть ли минус у этой реализации?

Comment: С моей точки зрения минусов нет. Но есть и другая точка зрения. ;)

Comment: )))Спасибо))все четк)

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю свои 5 копеек. Дефолтные методы в интерфейсе избавляют от такого гемороя как перелопачивание всего кода. Например, когда написаны тысячи строк кода, и вдруг, появляется острая необходимость дополнить интерфейс еще одним методом, то компилятор будет люто ругаться и просить реализовать новый метод во всех классах, которые заимплементились от этого интерфейса. Но стоит пометить новый метод как `default`и проблем с обязательной реализацией этого метода в классах не будет.